# Change column name in view using json view formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a view in SharePoint online where I need to override column name with a custom value.

Is it possible to do this using JSON View Formatting?

Ref:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting

Comment: related to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293459/sharepoint-online-formatting-column-headers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the **column header** and keep the list view as a standard SharePoint list view then **No**.

It is not possible to **just** change the column headers using JSON formatting.

If you want to customize the complete view and create a custom header then you can do that using view formatting. Check below View sample for reference:

[Custom Header](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/custom-header)

**Note**: Creating a custom header removes the standard features such as menus, sorting, moving, resizing, etc. In addition, the sticky header feature is now gone.

Comment: I flagged the broken link. in the meantime I think this is the new link: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/custom-header