# How to create a tooltip for Column Title on hover in MS Lists?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I created MS List where I need to add a tooltip for "Prioritization" Column name when mouse over the Column Name.

Tooltip text to be displayed: "Ranking: C- Critical, H - High, M - Medium, L - Low", but only when hovering over the Column Title and not the column content. It should be visible both in editing and view mode.

I'm struggling with it as I'm not a programmer. Appreciate your help.

Here is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$Prioritization]",
                "C"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground50",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Prioritization]",
                    "H"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Prioritization]",
                        "M"
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground50",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$Prioritization]",
                            "L"
                          ]
                        },
                        "sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground50",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$Prioritization]",
                                ""
                              ]
                            },
                            "",
                            "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "style": {
            "line-height": "16px",
            "height": "14px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Prioritization]",
                    "C"
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Prioritization]",
                        "H"
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$Prioritization]",
                            "M"
                          ]
                        },
                        "",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$Prioritization]",
                                "L"
                              ]
                            },
                            "",
                            {
                              "operator": ":",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": "==",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$Prioritization]",
                                    ""
                                  ]
                                },
                                "",
                                ""
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "span",
          "style": {
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
            "padding": "0 3px"
          },
          "txtContent": "[$Prioritization]",
          "attributes": {
            "class": {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$Prioritization]",
                    "C"
                  ]
                },
                "",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$Prioritization]",
                        "H"
                      ]
                    },
                    "",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$Prioritization]",
                            "M"
                          ]
                        },
                        "",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$Prioritization]",
                                "L"
                              ]
                            },
                            "",
                            {
                              "operator": ":",
                              "operands": [
                                {
                                  "operator": "==",
                                  "operands": [
                                    "[$Prioritization]",
                                    ""
                                  ]
                                },
                                "",
                                ""
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "customCardProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "Ranking: C - Critical, H - High, M - Medium, L - Low."
    },
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "beakStyle": {
      "backgroundColor": "white"
    }
  }
}
```

In addition the code added at the end for a tooltip damages the formatting of the ranks (color coding for radio buttons). Don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

For now, SharePoint Online does not support JSON formatting on column header in view formatting. Here is the [user voice post](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42412921-allow-formatting-column-headers-in-list-view-using) talking about this feature. You can vote on it to convey your thoughts and make MS develop team to consider about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of JSON formatting in SharePoint.

You **cannot** format the column headers using JSON formatting in SharePoint online.

**Similar threads**:

1. [SharePoint Online - formatting column headers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293459/sharepoint-online-formatting-column-headers/293463#293463)
2. [SharePoint Modern Column Header cuts off](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293760/sharepoint-modern-column-header-cuts-off/293764#293764)

I have created a [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/42412921-allow-formatting-column-headers-in-list-view-using) for the exact same requirements before.