# Is it possible to change the background colour of the title of a column in a list with JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to finalize a list and I want to change the color of my column titles.

I am not an admin in my company and i cant implement CSS easily.

Does someone know if its possible with JSON to change the color?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of JSON formatting in SharePoint.

You cannot format only the column headers using JSON formatting in SharePoint online.

---

You can format column headers using [JSON view formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting) but you will loose the SharePoint out of the box list view and you have to format list view from scratch.

**Similar thread**: [SharePoint Online - formatting column headers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/293459/sharepoint-online-formatting-column-headers/293463#293463)