# SPO List view where users cannot click the title to open the item details page

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

Is there a way to disallow user to click the title of the item on the SPO list view to open the item details page.

The reason being is that I have a view that shows selected columns in the list only and I don't want some users to be able to view all the columns in the list.

Comment: check my answer below. it should help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply JSON column formatting on your title column like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: However, user can open the list forms by double click anywhere on list item row - this is a default behavior in SharePoint. In that case you may need to use view formatting and create a completely customized list view. In this case you might loose few of the SharePoint functionalities. Check: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286588/change-column-name-in-view-using-json-view-formatting/286590#286590 and https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303892/sharepoint-modern-list-change-fill-color-of-column-headers/303893#303893

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you don't want to use JSON Formatting, then you can update view columns by editing view and add Title column which is not linked to Item menu using below steps:

1. Click on Edit View

[image]

2. Remove `Title (linked to item with edit menu)"` and add only `Title` column

[image]